# Determine whether the time range of one table entry overlaps with another KDB+/Q

Tags: datetime, time, kdb

I have a table like the following:

```
table:([] RIC:`A.N`A.N`A.N`GOOG.O`GOOG.O; 
startRange:2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000;
endRange:2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000)
```

I want to add a column "overlap" that is a boolean flag that is equal to 1 any time an entry has another entry (with the same corresponding RIC) that overlaps with it's time range.
So, for my table above, the first and third entries should be flagged because they're both for `A.N and have overlapping datetime ranges. The fourth and fifth entry should be flagged because they also have the same RIC and overlapping datetime ranges.

I honestly have no idea at all how to even approach this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a long-winded solution here but I think this covers your use case:

```
q)raze{update overlap:{any(x within'z)|y within'z}'[startRange;endRange]{x where y<>til count x}'[;i]count[i]#enlist flip(startRange;endRange)from x}each{select from table where RIC=x}each`A.N`GOOG.O
RIC    startRange                    endRange                      overlap
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000 1
A.N    2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000 0
A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000 1
GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000 1
GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000 1
```

To break this answer down, firstly we needed the time ranges to check for an overlap. We start with all the time ranges for a given RIC:

```
q)`overlap xcols raze{update overlap:count[i]#enlist flip(startRange;endRange)from x}each{select from table where RIC=x}each`A.N`GOOG.O
overlap                                                                                                                                                                          ..
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000)                                                        ..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000)                                                        ..
```

We want to exclude the time range for the entry we're working from:

```
q)`overlap xcols raze{update overlap:{x where y<>til count x}'[;i]count[i]#enlist flip(startRange;endRange)from x}each{select from table where RIC=x}each`A.N`GOOG.O
overlap                                                                                                                   RIC    startRange                    endRange          ..
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------..
(2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000) A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:5..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000) A.N    2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:0..
(2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000;2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000) A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:5..
,2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000                                                              GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:5..
,2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000                                                              GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:5..
```

And finally see if `startRange` or `endRange` are within these time ranges:

```
q)`overlap xcols raze{update overlap:{any(x within'z)|y within'z}'[startRange;endRange]{x where y<>til count x}'[;i]count[i]#enlist flip(startRange;endRange)from x}each{select from table where RIC=x}each`A.N`GOOG.O
overlap RIC    startRange                    endRange
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000
0       A.N    2022.01.03D09:32:04.000000000 2022.01.03D09:32:09.000000000
1       A.N    2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000
1       GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.000000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.000000000
1       GOOG.O 2022.01.03D09:31:54.100000000 2022.01.03D09:31:59.100000000
```

**EDIT:**

A faster solution

```
q)raze{update overlap:{$[any x within'z;1b;any y within'z]}'[startRange;endRange]{x where y<>til count x}'[;i]count[i]#enlist flip(startRange;endRange)from x}each{select from table where RIC=x}each`A.N`GOOG.O
```

Comment: when I apply this to my larger table with many many more RICs, do I need to replace the "each `A.N`GOOG.O" at the end with a list of distinct RICs in my table?

Comment: Correct, could use `exec distinct RIC from table`.

Comment: What's the time complexity of this implementation? Is it O(n^2) since it's moving through each element and again searching each element for comparison?

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issues? The initial select speed could be improved by applying an attribute to the table (`g#` or `p#` for example).

Comment: Yeah it's just a bit slow. I works perfectly, but it takes about 5 hrs to run for a 6 million data point table. I was just curious what the time complexity was. I also can't apply any attributes to the table I'm working with

Comment: Is the initial `{select from table where RIC=x}each exec distinct RIC from table` slow? How long does the whole solution take for just one sym? Are you selecting the whole table or only the columns you need?

Comment: That part is pretty quick, and it still takes a few minutes for just one sym. Selecting only the columns needed.

Comment: Added an edit to the original post which should be 2x as fast.

Comment: Does this edit delete rows or something? you're right, it's faster, but it removes all but the overlap, start time, and end time rows when I use it.

Comment: do you mean it removes the rows where overlap=1b?

Comment: Ah I meant columns, but the same thing happened when I ran it the old way so something else Is going on.

Comment: The result should be the same for both methods.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out what was going on. Thanks!